# how to setup dotenv in development and production?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon, dotenv

In my Express JS API server, I tried to use dotenv with a `.env` file for my environment setup.

I prefer to use the `.env` file for both development and production environment.

I am using nodemon for my development, currently if I include `-r dotenv/config` in package.json > start script:

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -r dotenv/config index.js"
    }
```

the variables setup correctly in `process.env` everwhere in the app

However, if I use script to config dotenv in `index.js` like this:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
// Environment variables
dotenv.config()
```

**seems `process.env` only configed in index.js page, I cannot get `process.env` variables in my middleware logic?**
I have put `dotenv.config()` executed at the very beginning before middleware executed

My questions are:
1. is my logic using `dotenv.config()` not a correct setup? why my middleware cannot get the same variables?
2. How to setup `process.env` variables read from `.env` file for both development and production? (I may use webpack to package my production version)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have other `import` statements before the `dotenv.config()` line, those modules will not have access to configured environments variables

Instead of

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

you can use

```js
import 'dotenv/config'
```

or use the following command to start your application, similar to how you have the development environment setup. If you have your transpiled output in `build` directory:

```
node --require dotenv/config build/index.js
```

reference:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import-